# find conditions query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a transition.  I would like to say that if the last transition (model: DistributionSheet, attribute:state) is closed, **then** display these results.  So I need this:

WHEN:

```
<% DistributionSheet.find(:all, :conditions => ["state = ?","closed"]).last %>
```

THEN:

```
<% Result.find(:all).each do |result| %>
  <%= result.name %>
<% end %>
```

Something like that.  Can anyone direct me please.
Thanks
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this stuff in your view, but that's another matter :-)

Is this what you mean? ...

```
<% if DistributionSheet.find(:last).state == "closed" %>
  <% Result.find(:all).each do |result| %> <%= result.name %> <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Agreed that this shouldn't be in the view.

Comment: Thanks Ant.  Where do you recommend I do this then?  The aim is to display all user results (model:Result) when the tranistion is closed.

Comment: You can also do `DistributionSheet.last.state` for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Just avoid doing queries in your views, for example you could move DistributionSheet.find(:last).state == "closed" into your DistributionSheet model and wrap in a method such as self.last_closed?, you can then call this from your controller then pass variables to your view, or render a different view if necessary.

Comment: help again. sorry.  If I have a field called 'sheet_id' and 'specimen_id' in a model called specimen and i need to say take the last 'sheet_id' and print the 'specimen_id' for that 'sheet_id' would it be something like this:

Comment: (Specimen.last.distribution_sheet_id == '?').each do |specimen| %>

Comment: <%= specimen.specimen_id %> <% end %>

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it as an if?

```
<%- if (DistributionSheet.where(:state => 'closed').last) -%>
  <% Result.all.each do |result| %>
    <%= result.name %>
  <% end %>
<%- end -%>
```

**Update**: Alternate interpretation of the question:

```
<%- if (DistributionSheet.last.state == 'closed') -%>
  <% Result.all.each do |result| %>
    <%= result.name %>
  <% end %>
<%- end -%>
```